# Collapsible Jquery Mobile css Changing affects size of collapsible

Tags: jquery, mobile

What my code does is set to fix the position of a collapsible div when it's top reach a determinate place when scrolling.

My collapsible div gets fixed, on the top of the page, that's ok, the problem is the size of the collapsible div changes and it gets smaller instead keeping with it's default width.

Here I'm attaching the code (all is fired on a scrollstart):

```
scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();    

if(scrollPos >= parseInt($("#cabecera").css("height").replace("px",""))){
    $("#cabecera").animate({height:0},function(){
        $("#lista").css({'top':0,'position':'fixed','width':"40%"})
        $("#lista").attr("data-role","collapsible")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the point, it's about changing the class .ui-collapsible.

So I guess that first I must save the initial width value of the class and then modify the .ui-collapsible class from the script and force to set the original width to the now modified fixed collapsible content.

If some one of you have a better solution, please post it.